# Key binding to change the face of a character

Tags: emacs, highlight

I'm curious as to whether or not there's a simple way to edit the face of a block of text using a function.

Specifically, I'm working on a calendar major mode that I created, and I want to define a function that will be bound to a keystroke within this major mode. I want to be able to mark a group of text, and then change its face using this keybinding to mark it as "done", etc.

I did some research and wasn't able to find this exact issue. Also, I know I can basically do this exact thing in org-mode, but I really want to create my own mode to enable more flexibility on my end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the 3-month mini-calendar as a basis to create your major-mode, then there is already a facility to do this.  To see how this looks like, type `M-x calendar` and then `M-x calendar-mark-holidays`.  To see how this works, you can type `M-x find-function RET calendar-mark-holidays RET` and see that it uses the function `calendar-mark-visible-date` -- so there you have it, that is your function of interest.  Drew Adams has a fancier calendar mark date that has some additional options:  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/calendar%2B.el .  These markings are overlays and can be controlled with priorities to have one supersede another so that it is not actually necessary to remove a color unless you want to.

Here is a quick example of a keyboard shortcut/function that uses the F5 key:  `(define-key calendar-mode-map [f5] (lambda () (interactive) (calendar-mark-visible-date (calendar-cursor-to-date 'signal-error) '(:background "yellow" :foreground "black"))))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately I'm not using the mini-calendar. I've created an engine that produces calendars which are full screen and raw text. It's actually based on the bash `cal` command. What I really need is a function that changes the font-lock-face on a marked area, if that's possible. I'd like to keep things general.

Comment: Drew Adams has a mark text library also https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=browse;oldid=HighLight;id=HighlightLibrary .  I use a modified version of `calfw`.  If you have not already seen `calfw`, it is the best calendar for Emacs:  https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw  And, I have a 12-month rotating calendar without instructions that you may wish to check out:  https://github.com/lawlist/lorg-calendar  You are probably going to want to use overlays or text-properties, but not font-lock per se.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ad hoc, not syntax, highlighting: You want to manually choose specific arbitrary text to highlight, and you want to choose the highlighting face to use for this or that chosen bit of text.

You can use library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)) to do that.

Command `hlt-choose-default-face` chooses the face to use for subsequent highlighting (it reads a face name or a color name, with completion).

Another way to choose the highlighting face is to use command
`hlt-next-face` or `hlt-previous-face`.  These cycle among a
smaller set of faces and background colors, the elements in the
list value of option `hlt-auto-face-backgrounds`.  You can use a
numeric prefix argument with these commands to choose any of the
elements by its absolute position in the list.

There are commands (e.g., `hlt-highlight`) to highlight or unhighlight the active region, or you can drag the mouse to highlight (or unhighlight).  By default they use the last default face you chose.

For persistent highlighting, see [Temporary or Permanent Highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary#PermanentHighlighting).

Comment: Are there methods of making this persistent?

Comment: Yes, see this section of the doc: [Temporary or Permanent Highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary#PermanentHighlighting).